# Implementing IEnumerable. Error.

Tags: c#, ienumerable

my Code is :

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IEnumerable
{
    public class MyEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public MyEnumerable(T[] items)
        {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new NestedEnumerator(this);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        // The enumerator definition.
        class NestedEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
        {
            public NestedEnumerator(MyEnumerable<T> coll)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(coll.items.SyncRoot);
                this.index = -1;
                this.coll = coll;
            }

            public T Current
            {
                get { return current; }
            }

            object IEnumerator.Current
            {
                get { return Current; }
            }

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                if (++index >= coll.items.Length)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = coll.items[index];
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public void Reset()
            {
                current = default(T);
                index = 0;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                try
                {
                    current = default(T);
                    index = coll.items.Length;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(coll.items.SyncRoot);
                }
            }

            private MyEnumerable<T> coll;
            private T current;
            private int index;
        }

        private T[] items;
    }

    public class EntryPoint
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MyEnumerable<int> integers = new MyEnumerable<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });

            foreach (int n in integers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am implementing this piece of code But i get an error. Can anybody help me what to do to error free this code? please help. 
My Errors are :

1->'IEnumerable' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

2->'IEnumerable.MyEnumerable' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'IEnumerable.MyEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the error you're receiving? (in case anyone's curious, here's an IDEone of the code above: http://www.ideone.com/RHu4V)

Comment: C'mon, let us know what the error is. We're here to help, not attend a job interview!

Comment: Error : 'IEnumerable' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Knowing the error(s) that you're getting might help?

Comment: Error: 'IEnumerable.MyEnumerable<T>' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'IEnumerable.MyEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.

Comment: Change `namespace IEnumerable` to `namespace BlingBlingWoo`

Comment: @chibacity You sure BlingBlingWoo isn't a reserved word, eh? ;-)

Comment: i have mentioned my errors in the question.. sorry lol :D :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is likely that you're using `IEnumerable` as your namespace when it's already a type in the system.

This means that your references to `IEnumerable` are refering to the current namespace and not the `IEnumerable` you're meaning to use (`System.Collections.IEnumerable`).

Try changing your namespace to something else.

Answer (score 3):

**Listen to what the compiler is telling you** and change your namespace to something sensible (like `BlingBlingWoo`)

```
...
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BlingBlingWoo
{
    public class MyEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    ...
```

Whats happening here is:

> Error : 'IEnumerable' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

You are trying to use the type `IEnumerable`, but you've created a namespace called `IEnumerable` and so the compiler things its a namespace.